# Disable sorting of child items in QTreeView

Tags: qt, sorting, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

I am using pyQt. How can I disable child items sorting in QTreeView/StandardItemModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) and reimplement its [lessThan](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) method.

Alternatively, create a subclass of [QStandardItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html) and reimplement its [less than](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#operator-lt) operator.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates the latter approach:

```
from random import sample
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.view)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        parent = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        keys = range(65, 91)
        for key in sample(keys, 10):
            item = StandardItem('Item %s' % chr(key), False)
            parent.appendRow(item)
            for key in sample(keys, 10):
                item.appendRow(StandardItem('Child %s' % chr(key)))
        self.view.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, text, sortable=True):
        QtGui.QStandardItem.__init__(self, text)
        self.sortable = sortable

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if getattr(self.parent(), 'sortable', True):
            return QtGui.QStandardItem.__lt__(self, other)
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: so, key - return False on __lt__ compassion if item is not sortable (if item not top level item in my case) ?

Comment: @Andrewshkovskii. Yes. In your case, it looks like you could use a normal `QStandardItem` for top-level items, and then just return `False` from `__lt__` for all child items (so the `sortable` attribute would not be needed).

Answer (score 1):

Call `setSortingEnabled(bool)` on your QTreeView instance. [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtreeview.html#sortingEnabled-prop) is the corresponding docu for c++ and [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtreeview.html#setSortingEnabled) is the link to pyqt api docu for this function

Comment: I do not need to disable sorting for all items, only for child items;